# How to add ORM-flavor to TypeScript and Angular2^?

Tags: javascript, angular, orm, data-modeling

Has anyone heard of an implementation of Object-Relation Mapping (ORM) to Angular2 based for example on local storage? I am only familiar with REST-full APIs which correspond to databases or other server side storages.

Finally I want to know **how to implement rich object models having (many-to-many, one-to-many, one-to-one) relations** to other models with pure client side JavaScript/TypeScript in Angular 2 and heigher.

Comment: Am I asking for something contradictory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution that fits to local storage databases like SQLite and persistant databases like MariaDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.

[image]

[TypeORM - ORM for TypeScript and JavaScript (ES7, ES6, ES5). Supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite, MS SQL Server, Oracle, WebSQL databases. Works in NodeJS, Browser, Ionic, Cordova and Electron platforms.](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm)